# How do i get a max value of a CGFloat without a base value?

Tags: swift

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = true

    if let touch = touches.first{
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

        lastPoint = currentPoint

        segmentTop = touch.location(in: self.view)
        segmentBottom = touch.location(in: self.view)
        segmentLeft = touch.location(in: self.view)
        segmentRight = touch.location(in: self.view)
    }
}
```

I am currently working on a project where my objective is to make a segment cropped around a drawing. To accomplish this I have to check the touch-location, so that i can output where the touch has been nearest to every edge. For instance, the the top of the segment will be where the touch-location has been closest to the top-edge, this is what I am trying to output, however I have nothing to base it on. It is a bit like making a high-score in a game, while here you have no previous high-score to base it on.

Comment: Unrelated but why are you calling `touch.location(in: self.view)` five times? Call it once. Use `currentPoint` to set the other four variables.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What value to you need the max of?

Comment: First of all I want to know how you generally you can find the max as well as min value of the touch location in either directions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear but I think you are looking for a way to track the min and max X and the min and max Y of the last touch point.

One solution would be something like this:

Declare properties to track the current min and max X and Y values:

```
var minX: CGFloat?
var maxX: CGFloat?
var minY: CGFloat?
var maxY: CGFloat?
```

Then for each touch point you compare each:

```
if let minX = minX {
    // See if this new point is less than the current min
    if lastPoint.x < minX {
        self.minX = lastPoint.x
    }
} else {
    // No current minX so use this value
    self.minX = lastPoint.x
}
```

Perform similar calculations for the other three values.

A simpler but similar solution would be to start with initial values and avoid the use of optionals:

```
var minX = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
var maxX = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
var minY = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
var maxY = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
```

Then each check becomes:

```
if lastPoint.x < minX {
    minX = lastPoint.x
}
if lastPoint.x > maxX {
    maxX = lastPoint.x
}
```

Repeat for the Y values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You understood my question, but  your solution don´t seem to work. I think this is because for instance lastPoint.x and minX always stays the same, I was actually trying something like this, but that was why I came here. .greateFiniteMagnitude and .leastNormalMagnitude doesnt show up I think because I have Xcode beta and a very new swift version

Comment: Are you declaring `minX` and friends as properties of the class (as you should be) or as variables of the `touchesMoved` method (don't do this)?

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
segmentTop = max(segmentTop, touch.location(in: self.view).y)
segmentBottom = min(segmentBottom, touch.location(in: self.view).y)
segmentLeft = min(segmentLeft, touch.location(in: self.view).x)
segmentRight = max(segmentRight, touch.location(in: self.view).x)
```

make sure segmentTop, segmentBottom, segmentLeft, and segmentRight are initially set to 0